# Jinja2's generate() returns entire rst template

Tags: python, jinja2, restructuredtext

I'm trying to create a restructuredText document (that I'll use `rst2pdf` on) using Jinja2 to fill in the values. Some bullet points on the document need to be included or left off depending on external factors, so when I found out Jinja2 had a `[generate()][1]` function to get a generator, I thought that would be perfect for the task.

Unfortunately, when I used it, the only item in the generator was the entire rst template (with values plugged in), not separated into lines like I was hoping for. Also, I haven't been able to locate much information beyond the linked docs about `generate()`, so I'm not sure what aspect needs fixing.

Here is my code:

```
doc_info = {"name": "Kaladin",
            "address": "Shattered Plains",}

env = Environment(loader=PackageLoader('src', 'templates'))

template = env.get_template("Example.rst")

template_gen = template.generate(doc_info)

print template_gen.next()  # Would be looped if it worked as expected
```

Example.rst:

```
.. header::

  +--------------------------------------------------------+
  |.. class:: center                                       |
  |                                                        |
  |**User Info**                                           |
  +------------------+-------------------------------------+
  |.. class:: right  |.. class:: left                      |
  |                  |                                     |
  |Name:             |{{ name }}                           |
  +------------------+-------------------------------------+
  |.. class:: right  |.. class:: left                      |
  |                  |                                     |
  |Address:          |{{ address }}                        |
  +------------------+-------------------------------------+

{{ name }} lives in {{ address }}
```

NOTE: In this example, the table will misalign because of the variable length of `name` and `address`, but in my actual code I adjust the spaces, so it's not the issue.

Using `render()` works just as expected, by the way, it's just that `generate()` doesn't give me what I expect.

Is there some way to indicate that I want the generator items to separate by end of line? Or am I doing something else wrong? If I'm misusing it and there's a better way, I'm open to that as well.

Comment: Can you show how you have the Example.rst file laid out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little late to the party (4 years!), but it seems like the `generate()` function works on for loops and if blocks, but your template doesn't have any of these.

To decide what to include in the output, use `{% if <external.factor> %}` and pass external factor into generate (or maybe `render()` -- not clear that `generate()` is needed for this application).

Comment: Well hey, better late than never! :D Hopefully this will help others in the future!